# How to use Pundit policy for two different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, ruby-on-rails-6

I have three models.

**User**

```
has_many :projects
```

**Project**

```
has_many :users
```

**Website**

```
belongs_to :project
has_many :users
```

I also use Active Admin and Pundit to manage my project and permissions. I need to control users to reach website objects if website's project is also user's project.

For this reason I prepare a code like this;

```
scope.where("#{@record.project.id.in? Project.where(id: ProjectUser.where(user_id: @user.id).ids).ids}")
```

but it returns error message:

> undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It says `@record` is nil, start by looking on why is it nil. It's hard to tell since you just show a line of code and no context.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

```
class Scope < Scope
 def resolve
   case @user.class.to_s
   when 'AdminUser'
     scope.all
   when 'User'
     project_user_array = ProjectUser.where(user_id: @user.id)
     project_ids = project_user_array.map {|object| object[:project_id] }
     scope.where(project_id: project_ids)
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

User `has_many :projects` - it gives you `project_ids` method for the user instance. Just use it:

```
scope.where(project_id: @user.project_ids)
```